# Create a pivot table without aggregate column in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql

How to convert in SQL server 2012

```
PatientId  Diagnosis
1             Detail1
1             Detail2
1             Detial3
2             Detail4
```

```
Into
PatientID    Diag1       Diag2        Diag3
1            Detail1     Detail2      Detail3
2            Detial4
```

[image]
Thankyou

Comment: This is a presentation concern, not a "data" concern: so you shouldn't do this in SQL - you should do this in your report system or end-user application.  Also, what happens if a patient has more than 3 diagnosis rows?